# Об append() в jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Значит я просто решил поиграть с jquery, написал такой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="message_area"></div>
    <textarea id="for_send" title="Test"></textarea>
    <button id="send">Submit</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Это был html, вот js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#send").click(function(){
    var text;
    text = $("#for_send").val();
    $('#message_area').append('<div></div>').text(text).addClass('.message');
});
});
```

Задача такова: пытаюсь вставлять сообщения(текст из div) в окно с сообщениями(#message_area) .Везде описывается метод append() "... вставляет в конец контента элемента для которого вызывается append...", а у меня что-то не так: не записывается контент, а заменяется, т.е. не вставляется в конец, а предыдущее содержимое #message_area удаляется и вставляется новое из #for_send Уже долго над этим сижу и никак не пойму в чем проблема.Размеры textarea указаны в css файле

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Давайте разберем что вы делаете

```
$('#message_area') // получаем элемент по id
    .append('<div></div>') // добавляем в конец элемента новый div
    .text(text) // меняем содержимое элемента*
    .addClass('.message'); // добавляем класс к элементу*
```

`*` вот тут у вас проблема, вы расчитываете, что `text` добавиться к созданному `div`, но метод `append` возвращает контекст, в котором он вызван, а не элемент, который мы передали как параметр для вставки

Выведите в консоль:

```
var element = $("<div id='div'></div>");
element.append("<a>"); // что вернется? Давайте проверим
element == element.append("<a>"); // true
```

То есть вы добавляете `div`, а потом вставляете текст в элемент `#message_area`, а вот метод `text` уже перезаписывает все содержимое, отсюда результат который вы описываете

**Решение**: создать дополнительную переменную и работать с ней

```
var messageDiv = $("<div class='message'></div>");
messageDiv.text(text);
$('#message_area').append(messageDiv);
```

**UPD** ( предложенный @Grundy)
Вариант без доп. переменной

```
$("<div class='message'></div>")
    .text(text)
    .appendTo('#message_area');
```

Comment: можно без доп переменной, если воспользоваться `appendTo`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так будет работать.

Вы в своем примере добавляете пустой див и присваиваете потом элементу с **id #message_area class = message** и вставляете в него текст из **$("#for_send").val()**

```
$(function(){
$("#send").on('click', function(){
    var text = $("#for_send").val();
    $('#message_area').append($('<div/>', {text: text, class: 'message'}));
});
});
```